# Javascript reset the whole form that contains default value

Tags: javascript, reset

How can I reset a HTML form with JavaScript? My form actually contains PHP default value.

I used this to clear:

```
        function reset(){
            document.getElementById("moduleform_insert").reset();
        }
```

It works perfectly when there is no `<input value="0">`.

Is there any method that can clear or I should grab each input value and one by one set to empty?

Hope someone would give some advice. Thanks.

Comment: This is how `reset` works, it set the value back to default value.

Comment: Emm which means there is no other ways?

Comment: You can clear inputs using `javascript`. If you give an example of the form then I'm sure someone will show you one or more methods of how this can be done.

Comment: @RICKYZHTC You need to clear them one by one after selecting them.. I have given an example to do the same with inputs of type text and number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do this.

```js
function reset(){
  jQuery("#moduleform_insert").val('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="moduleform_insert"  value="0" />
<input type="button" onClick="reset();" value="Reset" />
```

And if you have multiple input elements, you can change above `reset()` function to this one, which will loop through all your input elements and set their value to empty (you can put container id or class in front of input `jQuery(".container input")` ):

```
function reset(){
  jQuery("input").each(function(){
     jQuery(this).val('');
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

> It works perfectly when there is no .
>
> Is there any method that can clear or I should grab each input value
>   and one by one set to empty?

This is how [reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) works

> The **`HTMLFormElement.reset()`** method restores a form element's default
>   values. This method does the same thing as clicking the form's reset
>   button.

If you want to clear the values, then simply fetch them and clear them one by one

```
var form = document.getElementById("moduleform_insert");
var allNumberAndTextInputs = form.querySelectorAll("input[type='number'], input[type='text'] ");
Array.from( allNumberAndTextInputs ).forEach( function( ele ){
  ele.value = ""; //set the value to empty
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

```js
function reset() {
    document.getElementById("Form").reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="Form">
  <input type="text">
<input type="button" onClick="reset();" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = $('#myform');
form.find('input:text,textarea,select').val('');
form.find('input:radio,input:checkbox').each(function(){ 
    this.checked = false; 
});
```

This is the base code. You can add 'input:email', 'input:phone' and so on if you like. Or do something like this:

```
form.find('input').not(':hidden,:submit').val('');
```